# Code execution efficiency of window environment vs web worker environment in browser

Tags: javascript, web-worker

As we know web worker is strong API we got with HTML5 and web-worker execute code in its own area/env/its own thread.

And web page run code in window object/browser window context..

Both execution environment/process/thread are different.

Where as if we do some logic execution in window then it block the UI but web worker execution does not make any interference in UI.

My focus is to understand: who do task faster.

Because window need to handle multiple things like DOM nodes, events and other things but web-worker context does not need to worry about it.

Need thought which one is better to use complex and timely JavaScript logic execution.